# window.opener = null on browser mobile (ex: google chrome apps)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, window, window.opener

I'm having pop up authentication (instagram & twitter), the flow is:

1. in page `/home` user click button instagram auth
2. onClick --> `window.open(INSTAGRAM_AUTH_URL, '_blank', null)`
3. pop up window will authenticate instagram then redirect to page `/social-auth`
4. in `/social-auth` I did:

   ```
    if (window.opener) {
      window.opener.postMessage(data)
      window.close()
    }
   ```
5. in page `/home` I have listener `window.addEventListener('message', .....)` to receive the `postMessage` data from `/social-auth`

The problem is, on step 4 the `window.opener = null` on mobile browser (I tried on chrome apps).

---

Is there anything that I'm missing?
FYI it's working fine on desktop browser and I'm using React.js for the framework